# MD5 Hash password for WindowsIdentity - C#

Tags: c#, windows, hash, md5, password-protection

I'd like to use a hashed password with `WindowsIdentity`.
My Code is like:

```
IntPtr windowsUser = IntPtr.Zero;
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(
    String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr windowsUser);

public MainWindow()
{
    IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool success = LogonUser("Username", " ", "Password", 2, 0, out userToken);
    if (!success)
        return;
    WindowsIdentity newIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(userToken);
    using (newIdentity.Impersonate())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there any function to use `WindowsIdentity` with a hashed password? 
I don't want the password to be transmitted in clear text.
Thanks!

Comment: `LogonUser` does not transmit passwords in clear text, it already hashes the password before sending it off to the logon server. If you want to protect the password string in other locations, use [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.securestring#interop) and encrypted storage.

Comment: Hello Jeroen Mostert. 
Thanks for your answer. 
Even if LogonUser hashes the password before sending it, I have to write it down in clear text, right? 
I get the hashed password from an *.ini file and want to login the user with this hash..

Comment: Yes, you have to supply it in clear text -- there is no way to authenticate using only a hash. (At least, no *official* way; successfully authenticating with a pre-stored hash is used in some pass-the-hash attacks.) If at all possible, look at ways where you *don't* impersonate a user using stored credentials. If you must employ stored credentials (or the keys to decrypt them), store them securely through an OS-supplied mechanism like [`ProtectedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata).

Comment: Note that if logging in with a hash *was* possible, the hash would need to be stored just as securely as a plaintext password, because it would effectively have the same function! This is why it wouldn't help you to have the password hashed: sure, you couldn't read the password, but anyone who could read the hash could still log in as that user.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! You convinced me to try something else or just leave it like this. Thanks!